# How to update nested objects in React state?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here? From the console.log, I can see the date function is working correctly. However, even after `this.setState`, the timestamp isn't updated. Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: setState is asynchronous function. is the value not updated in the render function as well? If so can you provide a more complete example?

Comment: @TomSlutsky I see! I didn't know setState is an asynchronous function. I'll resolve this with async-await then! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `setState` with `callback`

According to official docs

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater, callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied.

```
this.setState((prevState)=>{
   userInfo:{
       ...prevState.userInfo,
       timestamp:timestamp
},()=>console.log(this.state.userInfo.timestamp)) // console.log here as setState is async operation
```

Comment: I see! I didn't know setState is an asynchronous function. I'll resolve this with async-await! Thanks alot!